# Clarification of a Nest Class Callback function in C++ for C programmer

Tags: c++, c, class, callback, nested

I would like help on how to understand the use of nested use of these C classes containing callbacks

```
  class MyServerCallbacks: public BLEServerCallbacks {
       void onConnect(BLEServer* pServer) {
           deviceConnected = true;
       };   
       
       void onDisconnect(BLEServer* pServer) {
           deviceConnected = false;
       }
  };

  // confusion on the next 3 lines
  class MyCallbacks: public BLECharacteristicCallbacks {
      void onWrite(BLECharacteristic *pCharacteristic) {
         std::string rxValue = pCharacteristic->getValue();

         if (rxValue.length() > 0) {
             Serial.println("*********");
             Serial.print("Received Value: ");
             for (int i = 0; i < rxValue.length(); i++)
                 Serial.print(rxValue[i]);

             Serial.println();
             Serial.println("*********");
         }
     }
 };
```

I am from a C background and am confused by the the part of the code highlighted in BOLD. In the second example `class MyCallbacks: public BLECharacteristicCallbacks` I am confused by the use of the "body of the code" that appears to be inside a function definition. I want to highlight that I am used to writing Code in C and find the way the class is being dereferenced as problematic. I have gone through literature and am unable to find any proper explanation and am blocked. I came across this code while learning about the ESP32 at this location: https://platformio.org/lib/show/1841/ESP32%20BLE%20Arduino/examples?file=BLE_uart.ino

May I kindly request that someone explains the validity of the two class definitions. I do understand that the answer will encompass references to the relevant header files which appears to have the same definitions.

My question is about the syntactic understanding of how these two class definitions need to be interpreted in light of their previous definitions in the header files. Please note that I am from a C background.

Answer (score 0):

There is no nested definition here.

I cleaned up the indentation of your code.  From this, we can see that `class MyServerCallbacks` and `class MyCallbacks` are defined as separate classes.  We can also see that the former defines two member function and that the latter defines one member function.